# How can I sum a column in a dataframe after a group_by?

Tags: r

I would like to create a dataframe using the group_by function and then sum a column based on the group_by. So far, I've only been able to sum the entire column rather than within the group.

I have a dataframe:

```
old_df <- data_frame(category1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                     category2 = c("2", "1", "3", "4"))
```

From here, I would like to group_by category1 ("a" and "b") and sum category2 for "a" and "b" individually. It would look like this:

```
new_df <- data_frame(category1 = c("a", "b"),
                     Sum_category2 = c("3", "7"))
```

I've tried a few things, and I thought this one below should work.

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
 group_by(category1) %>%
 summarize(Sum_category2 = sum(category2))
```

Everything I've tried so far just sums up the entire category2 column, which in this case would equal 10. How can I make it sum only within the grouping?

Comment: Why is `category2` set to a character variable? If I run your code, it returns an error because of that. If I set `category2` to numeric `c(2, 1, 3, 4)` your code works as expected.

Comment: You're right, category2 is numeric, my mistake. When I run the code this way, I just receive a 1 x 1 tibble that has the entire category2 column sum. Any ideas?

Comment: See the answer below from @user1357015. You can't get the output you describe from the data and code in the answer, so something must be different.

Comment: I ended up using the prefix `dplyr::summarize` and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you had the `plyr` package loaded too; that can cause issues with `summarise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using strings for category 2 but the following works just fine.

```
library(dplyr)

old_df <- data.frame(category1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                 category2 = c(2, 1, 3, 4))

old_df %>% group_by(category1) %>% summarize(sum_category = sum(category2))

old_df
    # A tibble: 2 x 2
  category1 sum_category
  <fct>            <dbl>
1 a                    3
2 b                    7
```

Comment: You can use `old_df$category2 <- as.double(old_df$category2)` to convert to a numeric vector

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, category2 is indeed a numeric already. However, when I run the code like above I just get a 1x1 tibble containing the total category2 sum. Any ideas?